# The format of a packet XBee S1

Tags: arrays, xbee

I am trying to write a java code that allows me to send a array from pc1 to pc2:

```
   byte[] payload =  -84  -19  0  5  117  114  0  19  91  76  106  97  118  97  46  108  97  110  103  46  79  98  106  101  0
```

During the reception, I got the array "tab" using the following statement:

```
   int tab[]=response.getProcessedPacketBytes() ;

   ===> tab: 0  30  129  0  0  72  0  172  237  0  5  117  114  0  19  91  76  106  97  118  97  46  108  97  110  103  46  79  98  106  101  0  215
```

what is the relationship between the two array? and how I can get my first array?

help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but:

First of all you are sending byte type array and receiving int type array -> this causes conversion from -84 to 172 and from -19 to 237.

Second of all : check if receiving buffer is empty when calling this "response.getProcessedPacketBytes" - probably you have already "0  30  129  0  0  72  0  " in this buffer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is an 0x81 frame type.  Read through the API mode documentation for your XBee module ([Series 1](http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000982_G.pdf) or [Series 2](http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000976_K.pdf)) to understand the fields,  You'll likely want to print your bytes in hex instead of signed decimal, since that's what the documentation uses.

Here's what you received:

```
0  30: length of frame (30 bytes)
129: frame type (0x81)
0  0: source address (0x0000, the coordinator)
72: RSSI (received signal strength)
0: options byte    
172  237  ...  101  0: your original message (unsigned bytes instead of signed bytes)
215: checksum of the bytes in the frame
```

Comment: If that's the case, be sure to mark this answer as "accepted" so others will know your question has been answered.